# use lodash template with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, lodash, nodemailer

I'm using 'lodash.template' like this

```
var compiled = _.template('<% _.forEach(image, function(image) { %><td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/<%- image.image %>"</td><% }); %>');
```

I then generate emailHTML like this

```
res.render('templates/reset-password-email', {
          name: name,
          qc: qc,
          images: compiled(qc),
          appName: appName
        }, function (err, template) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
          emailHTML = template;
          callback(null, arr);
        });
```

I then send email like this

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailer.options);

      var mailOptions = {
        to: 'user@email.com',
        from: config.mailer.from,
        subject: 'subjet',
        attachments: [
          {
            path: filePath
          }
        ],
        html: emailHTML
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        //done(err, 'done');
      });
```

The problem that I'm having is that {{images}} which is the compiled lodash.template is being displayed as text instead of Html. For example the html below is being displayed as text not as html.

```
<td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8e580-b7e3-11e6-bea-c3c74fd.jpg"</td>
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. As always thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You `<img>` tag is not closed. Add the closing `>` and it should work find.

Comment: I tried with both > and /> and neither seem to have helped. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Look at the last line of code you gave: `<td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/8e580-b7e3-11e6-bea-c3c74fd.jpg"</td>
` the img tag is not closed, did you try to fix it (not in the lodash template) and see if this works?